# Declare a typesafe typesafe const object in typescript

Tags: typescript, prisma

I am working with Prisma which generates query return types based on the structure of the parameter passed into the invocation of the query.

For example:

```
const response = await Prisma.user.findUnique({ 
    where: { name: 'A name' },
    select: { name: true, email: true }
);
```

Will query the user table for a user with the name 'A name' and return an object with the `name` and `email` properties.

Prisma exports a `UserSelect` type which is defined to be something like

```
export type UserSelect {
  name?: boolean
  email?: boolean
  ...
}
```

Whilst editing the parameter object inline, vscode is able to provide full intellisense of parameters, however, I have several places where I am querying the same property selections so I wanted to try and pull out some reusable selections.

```
export const DefaultUserSelection = {
  name: true,
  email: true,
} as const
```

This works and Prisma still infers the correct type information for the return type of the query, however, because typescript doesn't know what type the selection is supposed to satisfy, there is no intellisense.

Declaring `DefaultUserSelection: Prisma.UserSelection` breaks the type inference of the query.

Is it possible to convey that the object I am authoring should be a const assertion, AND satisfy the `Prisma.UserSelection` type?  I tried `{} as Prisma.UserSelection as const` but typescript complains that a const assertion can only be applied to a literal object.

I could just author the object as `as Prisma.UserSelection`, then swap it to `as const` when I'm done, but it's a bit clunky and would make future changes harder.

Comment: I see TS has (very recently) added the `satisfies` keyword for what looks like exactly this usecase, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator.  I'm using 4.9.3 though and the keyword doesn't seem recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the new (ts 4.9) [`satisfies` keyword](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator).

```
export const DefaultUserSelection = {
  name: true,
  email: true,
} satisfies Prisma.UserSelect;
```

This provides full intellisense whilst defining the properties on the object, whilst maintaining the most narrow `as const` type.

In VS Code I had to ensure it was using my local project ts version (4.9.3) by specifying `typescript.tsdk` in my workspace `settings.json` file.